# Merge two arrays side by side where one can be shorter than the other

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, merge

Say I have hot and new news articles. I want to display them side by side in the view. It may of course be that there are more hot news than new news (at the morning for example) and vice versa. This would lead to an uneven length of the columns.

That's why I'm building two arrays. One with the hot news and one with the new ones.

```
$hot = array(
    'hotObj 1',
    'hotObj 2',
    'hotObj 3',
    'hotObj 4',
);

$new = array(
    'newObj 1',
    'newObj 2',
);
```

What I want as a result is this:

```
$hot = array(
    'hotObj 1',
    'newObj 1',
    'hotObj 2',
    'newObj 2',
    'hotObj 3',
    'hotObj 4',
);
```

How can I achieve this? It shouldn't matter which array is longer. 
array_merge() would just put the second array at the end which is not what I want.

Comment: Don't your news entries have IDs? If they do, just index the array with the post's ID.

Comment: I think this wouldn't help. Since the new articles have the highest ID they would always be at the end. But I want them side by side with the hot ones. In fact it's the same what array_merge would do. It would just put the new articles at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it simply using `for` loop, without using `sort` or `array_merge` function like as

```
$count = (count($hot) > count($new)) ? count($hot) : count($new);

$result = [];

for($i= 0; $i < $count;$i++){
    if(isset($hot[$i])){
        $result[] = $hot[$i];
    }
    if(isset($new[$i])){
        $result[] = $new[$i];
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => hotObj 1
    [1] => newObj 1
    [2] => hotObj 2
    [3] => newObj 2
    [4] => hotObj 3
    [5] => hotObj 4
)
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/eOTbe)

Comment: Thanks - sometimes it can be so simple. The problem although is that this would only work if I have more hot ones than new ones.

Comment: Yes that can be the case

Comment: Maybe just count both and loop through the bigger array. Would work but can't tell if that would be the best solution.

Comment: Check the updated answer no need to take care of which one is greater

Comment: Perfect. This indeed is a really great solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a loop for sum of both array and insert it as required. 
Try following (working) -

```
$hcount=count($hot);
$ncount=count($new);
$max=$hcount+$ncount;
$result=array();
$i=0;
$j=0;
$k=0;
while($i<=$max)
{
 if($i%2==1 && $j<$ncount)
 {
  $t=$new[$j++];
 }
 else
 {
   if($k<$hcount)
    $t=$hot[$k++];

 }
 $result[$i]=$t; 
    $i++;
}

print_r($result);
```

**output**

```
Array ( [0] => hotObj 1 [1] => newObj 1 [2] => hotObj 2 
[3] => newObj 2 [4] => hotObj 3 [5] => hotObj 4 [6] => hotObj 4 )
```

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate your answer. My thinking was also a bit complicated like yours. Well, look at the other answer how simple it can be :)

Comment: yep @sleepless , you are right thanks to Uchiha and stackoverflow , and congo for you .. finished with a great solution. happy coding :)