# Passing two variables into a 'foreach' loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I need help regarding a `foreach()` loop. aCan I pass two variables into one `foreach` loop?

For example,

```
foreach($specs as $name, $material as $mat)
{
    echo $name;
    echo $mat;
}
```

Here, `$specs` and `$material` are nothing but an array in which I am storing some specification and material name and want to print them one by one. I am getting the following error after running:

> **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' on foreach line.**

Comment: use for loop for that

Comment: You didn't specify how it should work, does $specs and $material have the same length? If not, then what?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? zipping the arrays, or combining them?

Answer (score 27):

In the Beginning, was the For Loop:

```
$n = sizeof($name);
for ($i=0; i < $n; $i++) {
   echo $name[$i];
   echo $mat[$i];
}
```

Comment: This is the way to do what (I think) the op is asking for, however, care should be taken to check if $name and $mat have the same number of elements. No one likes an IndexOutOfBounds exception. I'm not familiar with the exact syntax in php (haven't worked with it in a few years), but might I suggest adding that into your code?

Comment: I need to change at least 5 other characters to make the edit i -> $i
:(

Answer (score 14):

You can not have two arrays in a `foreach` loop like that, but you can use `array_combine` to combine an array and later just print it out:

```
$arraye = array_combine($name, $material);

foreach ($arraye as $k=> $a) {
     echo $k. ' '. $a ;
}
```

[**Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6XWUdW):

```
first 112
second 332
```

But if any of the names don't have material then you must have an empty/null value in it, otherwise there is no way that you can sure which material belongs to which name. So I think you should have an array like:

```
$name = array('amy','john','morris','rahul');
$material = array('1w','4fr',null,'ff');
```

Now you can just

```
if (count($name) == count($material)) {
    for ($i=0; $i < $count($name); $i++) {
        echo $name[$i];
        echo $material[$i];
 }
```

---

Just FYI: If you want to have multiple arrays in `foreach`, you can use `list`:

```
foreach ($array as list($arr1, $arr2)) {...}
```

Though first you need to do this: `$array = array($specs,$material)`

```
<?php
    $abc = array('first','second');
    $add = array('112','332');
    $array = array($abc,$add);

    foreach ($array as list($arr1, $arr2)) {
         echo $arr1;
         echo $arr2;
    }
```

The output will be:

```
first
second
112
332
```

And still I don't think it will serve your exact purpose, because it goes through the first array and then the second array.

Comment: What should i pass in the foreach loop for specs and material?

Comment: @ManishMishra Check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922285/merge-two-arrays-side-by-side-where-one-can-be-shorter-than-the-other/32922437#32922437)

Comment: is it mentioned  both array will have same count??

Comment: Nope it isn't @RohitKumar

Comment: "array_combine:Both arrays must have equal number of elements!" , so it will be a problem

Comment: @RohitKumar if he doent have equal number of element and array structure like that than  there is no way to check which material for which user

Comment: Why do you even suggest `list` if it’s not going to help (and it’s not)?

Comment: @KRyan i am just telling op how to use multiple array with foreach and thats why i am telling that that list with for each isnt the direct answer .. and for that very reason i am also telling to use another method which solve his purpose

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [`MultipleIterator`](http://php.net/multipleiterator) of SPL. It's a bit verbose for this simple use case, but works well with all edge cases:

```
$iterator = new MultipleIterator();
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($specs));
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($material));
foreach ($iterator as $current) {
    $name = $current[0];
    $mat  = $current[1];
}
```

The default settings of the iterator are that it stops as soon as one of the arrays has no more elements and that you can access the current elements with a numeric key, in the order that the iterators have been attached (`$current[0]` and `$current[1]`).

Examples for the different settings can be found in the [constructor documentation](http://php.net/manual/multipleiterator.construct.php).

Comment: @chx btw i dont really see any difference between your and his answer .. i know both uses different approaches but back end working is quite identical ... surely this answer describe nice way to do it but still i like your way

Comment: Because it can handle all cases via the constructor flags as linked.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the ways to do this:

```
foreach ($specs as $k => $name) {
  assert(isset($material[$k]));
  $mat = $material[$k];
}
```

If you have `['foo', 'bar']` and `[2 => 'mat1', 3 => 'mat2']` then this approach won't work but you can use `array_values` to discard keys first.

Another apprach would be (which is very close to what you wanted, in fact):

```
while ((list($name) = each($specs)) && (list($mat) = each($material))) {
}
```

This will terminate when one of them ends and will work if they are not indexed the same. However, if they are supposed to be indexed the same then perhaps the solution above is better. Hard to say in general.

Comment: php really have weird amount of function and way .. nice, i didnt knew about that idea of while loop ( http://codepad.viper-7.com/p2N7EU )

Answer (score 2):

Do it using a `for` loop...

Check it below:

```
<?php
    $specs = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
    $material = array('x', 'y', 'z');
    $count = count($specs) > count($material) ? count($specs) : count($material);
    for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++ )
    {
        if (isset($specs[$i]))
            echo $specs[$i];
        if (isset($material[$i]))
            echo $material[$i];
    }
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
axbyczd
```

Comment: though this works but its hard to know is some material doesnt exist  which material is for which user

Comment: if it is a requirement then both array should be tied up in one ... as in your answer @NullPoiиteя

Answer (score -1):

Simply use a `for` loop. And inside that loop, extract values of your array:

```
For (I=0 to 100) {
    Echo array1[i];
    Echo array2[i]
}
```

Comment: Will it compile (e.g. "For")? Isn't PHP case-sensitive?

Comment: Yes, but my mobile isn't